# Upload picture as Base64 string with volley returns warning: LogSlowRequest

Tags: java, php, android, upload, android-volley

I want to upload a picture from my app to a server. Because ftp connection isn't possible, I want to upload the picture as request with POST.

I use volley for my app. When I convert the pic to a Base64 String and send it to my server I get the warning:

> D/Volley: [50697] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for
>   request=<[ ] http://domain.com/api.php 0x3ce314bb NORMAL 1>
>   [lifetime=5264], [size=2], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]

This is my upload class:

```
public class Upload {

    private Context context;

    public Upload(Context _context){
        context = _context;
    }

    public void upload(final File file){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://domain.com/api.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("DEBUG","RESPONSE: " + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("a","text");
                params.put("b",convertPic(file.getPath()));
                params.put("c","text");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }

    private String convertPic(String path)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    private String convertString(String s){
        return Base64.encodeToString((s).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```

For testing, my php script just check the $_POST fields:

```
<?php
    header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(isset($post['a']) && $post['a'] != "" && isset($post['b']) && $post['b'] != "" && isset($post['c']) && $post['c'] != ""){
        echo 'OK';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add retry:

```
sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Make: DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES to 0

Comment: The Upload works, respectively the check of the $_POST fields (see the php code). But I don't know why I get this warning.